# AttributeError: type Object 'Widget' has no attribute '_ipython_display_'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

In one of my python test case I have mockcomm object and in the mockcomm function I am using ipywidgets. Recently Upgraded ipywidgets version from 7 to 8. The code is working fine in version 7 of ipywidgets but when upgraded I am facing the below error. Saying Object has not attribute defined. did any one faced the error can help me.

[image]

Comment: Just removed the line and everything working fine. Don't know what exactly it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1811), from ipywidgets 8, widgets uses `_repr_mimebundle_` instead of `_ipython_display_`.

So `_widget_attrs['_ipython_display_']` will raise `KeyError`. Use `_repr_mimebundle_` as key will sovle problem.